# Do elemental resistances stack with magical resistance

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I play a breton so have some magical resistance. I gather that this resists all magic. So if I have 25% magic resistance and 25% frost resistance, do I actually have 50% frost resistance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do magic resistance and flame, frost and shock resistance stack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38094/do-magic-resistance-and-flame-frost-and-shock-resistance-stack)

Comment: If I'm reading the questionc correctly, the proposed duplicate asks if resistances of the same kind, but from different sources stack. This question asks if magic resistance stacks with elemental resistances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two effects stack multiplicatavely, not additively, up to a maximum of 80%.

To use your example, you'd end up with 32% resistance.

Comment: Cheers, what is the formula?

Comment: @DeanMc multiplicative means Damage Input * (1-Resist Element%) = 1st aggregate. 1st aggregate * (1-Resist Magic%) = final result. Because they're being multiplied, the order is irrelevant, and they'll both return the same diminished result.

Comment: You mean 44.25% resistance? (.75)^2=56.25